# Ubuntu WSL installation error

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install the Ubuntu 18.04 WSL on Windows 10. Download (manual) seemed to go fine, and when I did Add-AppxPackage in Powershell I didn't get an error message.  But when I try to do the final installation in the Bash shell to establish username and password, I get "The system cannot find the file specified."  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: If you have downloaded the Appx file then extract it with any unzipping tool (for example 7zip) in a folder and run the ubuntu.exe in it.

Comment: Thanks!  Before trying this, I tried downloading from the Microsoft Store instead.  For some reason, that worked.  It saved it in a different location (where, I'm not sure).  The manual download saved it to the System32 folder.  This one...?  But anyway, the install went through this time.